# statistical errors associated to Monte Carlo sampling

Tags: statistics, monte-carlo

I have $n$ successive observation $A_\mu  $  of a quantity $A$ and I need to understand how  the expectation values of the square of the statistical error depends from the  autocorrelation time but a single step in the demonstration is giving me trouble. the author of the book (Monte Carlo simulations in statistical physics -Binder) wrote :

\begin{align*}
\langle {(\delta A)^2} \rangle 
&= \bigg\langle \bigg[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\mu =1}^n (A_\mu - \langle A \rangle) \bigg]^2 \bigg\rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{\mu=1}^n \langle(A_\mu -\langle A \rangle)^2 \rangle + \frac{2}{n^2}\sum_{ \mu_1= 1}^n \sum_{\mu_2 = \mu_1 +1}^n \bigg(\langle A_{\mu_1} A_{\mu_2} \rangle- \langle A\rangle \bigg)
\end{align*}

changing the summation index $\mu_2 $ to  $\mu_1 +\mu $  with $ \mu = \mu_2 - \mu_1$this equation can be rewritten as :

$$ \langle {(\delta A)^2} \rangle   = \frac{1}{n} \bigg[\langle A^2\rangle  - \langle A \rangle  ^2 + 2 \sum_{\mu =1}^n \bigg( 1-\frac{\mu}{n} \bigg) \bigg(\langle A_0 A_\mu \rangle - \langle A \rangle  \bigg) \bigg]        $$

how does this change in the summation index works?

please help me understand this passage

Comment: At root this is a math-stat question, but the notation is that used by physicists. It may get a better answer on our 'physics' site. // Meanwhile, for mathematicians: $\langle X \rangle$ means $E(X)$ and I think $\mu$ has nothing to do with population mean and can be read as $i.$

Comment: ah yes, thank you for clarifying it , i didn't think the notation would be misleading